# checking user's role during login using aspnet identity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on asp.net application. I have aspnetroles table with 4 roles:

```
**Id    Name**
1   Admin
4   Consumer
2   Provider
3   SaleUser
```

In AccountController Register Action method, I have added this:

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                **UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.UserRole);**
```

Now I am checking while login in login action result like this:

I see that aspnetusers and aspnetuseroles tables have correct data.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);


   if (User.IsInRole(model.UserRole))
                            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
```

but condition fails. How can I check if user belongs to specific role.

I have added following line in Startup.cs ConfigureAuth method:

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

and this class in identityConfig class:

```
 public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> store) : base(store)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(roleStore);
        }
    }
```

and this code in accountcontroller:

```
  private ApplicationRoleManager roleManager;
        public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
        {
            get
            {
                return this.roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            }
            private set { this.roleManager = value; }
        }
```

but still same issue

**Update**

```
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity);

if (User.IsInRole(model.UserRole))
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
else
{
    AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = null;

    model.Roles = GetRoles();
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "You cannot login as " + model.UserRole);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: does `if (User.IsInRole(model.UserRole))` typo in updated code section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this

```
if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
{
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity);

    if (user.IsInRole(model.UserRole))
    {     
         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = null;
        model.Roles = GetRoles();
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You cannot login as " + model.UserRole);
        return View(model);
    }
}

ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
return View(model);
```

The problem is that `User` is created depending on the cookies that you have sent to the browser, but at that point you haven't send them yet.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Only one issue. If i select wrong role, I get error message and after that when i try to login again, I get this message "The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user."

Comment: @user1125955 The point is that when the role is wrong just set `AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant` to `null`

Comment: I added that, and now it doesn't show that error on second login. but it is not loging in now. please check question updates.

Comment: @user1125955 if I correctly understand, you need to reject login when selected role is wrong yes?

Comment: @user1125955 please add result check, updated my code

Comment: I had a problem with `AuthenticationManager` refrence. For this i used `Microsoft.Owin.Security` refrence. I also used `IAuthenticationManager` interface and Initilized if from constructor.
so my code is `var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(_authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity);`